# how to set gradle build with version info from git automatically?

Tags: git, gradle

inside project build.gradle

```
allprojects{
    version '' //how to set this?
}
```

How to set the version to current git's branch name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [palantir-git-version](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version) plugin; see the example below.
(various other Gradle plugins exist; they are usually based on Jgit).

This will set the version to `branch_#[short-git-hash]`; if you want to use the branch name only, use `version(details.branchName)` .

---

**sample**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.gitversion:gradle-git-version:0.12.0-rc2"
  }
}

apply plugin: 'base'

allprojects{
  apply plugin: "com.palantir.git-version"

  def details = versionDetails()
  version(details.branchName + "_" + details.gitHash)
  println "version=$version"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it stopped working with gradle 7

Comment: You can use 0.12.2 with gradle 7. Thx to alecbarber for this comment : https://github.com/palantir/gradle-git-version/issues/353#issuecomment-901627430

Comment: This plugin's only drawback is it does not allow version start with `v`...

Comment: This plugin is very restrictive and you can't really customize tag patterns

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plain git CLI commands. It will be more complecated but without additional libs.

```
allprojects {
    def gitBranchName = { ->
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'branch', '--show-current'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return stdout.toString().trim()
    }

    def gitHash = { ->
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
            standardOutput = stdout
        }
        return stdout.toString().trim()
    }

    version("$gitBranchName" + "_" + "$gitHash")
}
```